# Invalid Data Extension Key Field Reference

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, lookup, data

I have just started learning email studio and I need help.
I am writing personilized email. I have two DE: Contacts and Opportunities.
Trying to get data from DE Opportunities I use this code:

```
%%[ var @opportunityName, @opportunityCloseDate set @opportunityName = Lookup("Opportunities","Name",ContactId, subscriberid) set @opportunityCloseDate = Lookup("Opportunities","CloseDate",ContactId, subscriberid) ]%% 
Active opportunities:<br>
%%=v(@opportunityName)=%% is active till %%=v(@opportunityCloseDate)=%%
```

And while testing I get such Error:
The subscriber preview failed to generate. Review the details, correct all issues, and try again.
Invalid Data Extension Key Field Reference. The key field name does not exist in the data extension. Data Extension: Opportunities Invalid Field: 3 Parameter Name: keyValues[0].Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming 'ContactId' is a field in your DE.

It should be:

```
%%[ 
   
    var @opportunityName, @opportunityCloseDate 
    set @subscriberid = _subscriberkey
    set @opportunityName = Lookup("Opportunities","Name","ContactId", @subscriberid) 
    set @opportunityCloseDate = Lookup("Opportunities","CloseDate","ContactId", @subscriberid) 
 ]%%
Active opportunities:
%%=v(@opportunityName)=%% is active till %%=v(@opportunityCloseDate)=%%
```

Refer the [Lookup Function](https://ampscript.guide/lookup/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really the reason was in format of ConactId. Now it works! ))